# Bootstrap Carousel in Rails app, showing all images and no thumbnails. Displaying images from database in Carousel

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm adding a this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/55Z0v Bootstrap carousel to a rails app.

The pictures I wan't to show in the Carousel comes from the `image.rb` model.

The thing is when I add the logic to display the images in the carousel, they are appearing on top of each other.

I'm not sure what to do, but I understand that the Carousel is displaying all images for the selected product.

I have worked with bootstrap carousels before, but only in pure html/css, so working on it in a Rails app is new for me.

Can someone please advise me how I can make the images appear like it should normally?

Below is the carousel code in the `show.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='carousel-custom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
        <div class='carousel-outer'>
            <!-- me art lab slider -->
            <div class='carousel-inner '>
                <div class='item active'>
                    <% @product.images.each do |image_product| %>
                        <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "zoom_05" %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>

                <script>
                  $("#zoom_05").elevateZoom({ zoomType    : "inner", cursor: "crosshair" });
                </script>
            </div>
            <!-- sag sol -->
            <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
            </a>
            <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
            </a>
        </div>
                    <!-- thumb -->
        <ol class='carousel-indicators mCustomScrollbar meartlab'>
            <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='0' class='active'> 
                <% @product.images.each do |image_product| %>
                    <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:small), class: "img-responsive", id: "zoom_05" %>
                <% end %>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({axis:"x"});
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken the problem is that all the parents `div` of the images has the classes `item active`, and only must has the `active` class.

Also look at `data-slide-to` attribute of the `li`s inside the `ol` element.

> ```
> <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to='0' class='active'> 
>   <% @product.images.each do |image_product| %>
>     <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:small), class: "img-responsive", id: "zoom_05" %>
>   <% end %>
> </li>
> ```

You are alwasys adding a slide in the position zero.

It must be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='carousel-custom' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
        <div class='carousel-outer'>
            <!-- me art lab slider -->
            <div class='carousel-inner '>
                <% @product.images.each_with_index do |image_product, index| %>
                    <div class="<%= index == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item' %>" >
                        <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive", id: "<%= index == 0 ? 'zoom_05' : '' %>" %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>

                <script>
                  $("#zoom_05").elevateZoom({ zoomType    : "inner", cursor: "crosshair" });
                </script>
            </div>
            <!-- sag sol -->
            <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='prev'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
            </a>
            <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-custom' data-slide='next'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
            </a>
        </div>
                    <!-- thumb -->
        <ol class='carousel-indicators mCustomScrollbar meartlab'>
            <% @product.images.each_with_index do |image_product, index| %>
                <li data-target='#carousel-custom' data-slide-to="<%= index %>" class="<%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>" >
                    <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:small), class: "img-responsive", id: "" %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".mCustomScrollbar").mCustomScrollbar({axis:"x"});
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

In the iterator with `index == 0` I check that if its the first image to set the `active` class.

Also, with the same thing, in the `li's` inside the `ol` I set the `slide-to` attribute.

Comment: @codergirl I have found another bug in the code you posted, the `slide-to` attribute in the `li`s from inside the `ol`

Comment: Sorry @MatayoshiMariano, I accepted to quickly,  this isn't working quit right, your previous code is working better, if I implement this code the thumbnails are not visible, and the carousel main image is stuck on only one image... I can't really figure out why since the `index == 0`makes sense to me.

Comment: Also if I add more than two images to each product, everything breaks. As in the carousel can´t slide between more than 2 images, thats strange

Comment: @codergirl I forgot to add `item` as a class if the indexaci&#243;n os different from zero. Aldo I added the `&quot;&quot;` to the code in the tags that have `&lt;%=`.
If It is not working, I will take a look tommorow